# When I tried to run my python program, I encountered this Django import error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I tried running a python program on my local machine, I encountered this error:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 2 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): auth.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
April 29, 2019 - 19:29:41
Django version 2.2, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Intern\Diversity_Policy_Site\mysite\wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\django.py", line 2, in <module>
    '\n\n'
ImportError:

Your WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0
This can be fixed by following the upgrade instructions at:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0



The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 50, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

I tried the suggested link in the error message, but it didn't work out.

Here are the versions:

```
Brotli==1.0.7
certifi==2019.3.9
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
elasticsearch==7.0.0
elasticsearch-dsl==7.0.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2==2.8.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.1
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

I have also asked a similar question today, but I still can't solve this problem, and I have tried looking at the solution from other posts, and they are not very helpful.

Here is the content of my setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku 
import dj_database_url

config = dj_database_url.config

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
DEBUG = False

# Experimenting here
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost"]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
# from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
 
# def get_env_variable(var_name):
#     try:
#         return os.environ[var_name]
#     except KeyError:
#         error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
#         raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

# one for development (maybe move that to local postgres) and another for running and development
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        }
}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

#STATIC_URL = './blog/staticfiles/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     #'/Diversity_Policy_Site/blog/static',
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
# )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The instructions are in the error message. You should read it! BTW there is an other problem hidden in there.

Comment: Look into [maintaining multiple settings.py files](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html) for various environments or [dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) to keep your secrets secret. Also, change your secrets and DB password.

Comment: @mbhargav294 thanks for the reminder, I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution online:
frist do: python manage.py migrate
then do: pip uninstall whitenoise
then do: pip install "whitenoise<4"

Also, appreciate everyone who posted suggestion on this post.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change the `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'` to `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'`

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't work, but thanks for the help.

Comment: is the project called mysite? otherwise change it to `WSGI_APPLICATION = '<<your_project_name>>.wsgi.application'`

Comment: How do I find the project name? I mean, the whole folder is called "Diversity_Policy_Site", but the folder that the setting.py in is called mysite

Comment: hmm, I mean I guess it doesn't hurt to try with the Diversity_Policy_Site